# Clear Visual Studio's Addin Manager cache

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Earlier today I uninstalled a trialware from DevArt that has hosed Visual Studio's Solution Explorer. I've uninstalled it but some remnants remain though SQL Complete's menu is no longer appearing in VS's menu bar but it does show up a unchecked entry in the Add-in manager.

Is there a 'clear cache' function I can execute to restore VS's functionality?

thx

vs10 pro 64bit

An exception was encountered while constructing the content of this frame.  This information is also logged by running the application with the /log parameter on the command line, which stores results in "C:\Users\client\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ActivityLog.xml".

Exception details:
System.ArgumentException: String cannot have zero length.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()